# mongodb c# update embedded document

Tags: c#, mongodb

How can I update some embedded documents, for example:

I have object:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5648c70f574b7e15b0a2ddda"), 
    "Username" : "admin@yourStore.com", 
    "Email" : "admin@yourStore.com", 
    "ShoppingCartItems" : [
        {
            "ProductId" : NumberInt(4), 
            "AdditionalShippingChargeProduct" : NumberInt(0), 
        }, 
        {
            "ProductId" : NumberInt(4), 
            "AdditionalShippingChargeProduct" : NumberInt(0), 
        },
        {
            "ProductId" : NumberInt(5), 
            "AdditionalShippingChargeProduct" : NumberInt(0), 
        },
    ], 
}
```

I need update field **AdditionalShippingChargeProduct = 5** but for only where **ProductId equals 4**.

This code only updates the first position, I need to update all the matching positions.

```
    var builder = Builders<Customer>.Filter;
    var filter = builder.ElemMatch(x => x.ShoppingCartItems, y => y.ProductId == 4);
    var update = Builders<Customer>.Update
        .Set("ShoppingCartItems.$.AdditionalShippingChargeProduct", 5);

    var result = customer.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update).Result;
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1):

{ShoppingCartItems.ProductId:4}, {$set:{"ShoppingCartItems.$.AdditionalShippingChargeProduct":6 }}

Comment: This comment could do with some additional commentary, and proper code formatting